# How can i upload image using Ckeditor 5 Classic with laravel?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor5

I am trying to set up image upload with Ckeditor 5 for my laravel project but image upload it not working

```
<textarea name="body" class="editor">{{old('body')}}</textarea>
            <script>
                ClassicEditor
                        .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ) )
                        .then( editor => {

                        } )
                        .catch( error => {
                                console.error( error );
                        } );
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not used Ckeditor 5 for this but used summernote for my editor.

Here's the code in the controller which handles the request:

```
// check if files were uploaded and process them
            $uploadedFiles = $request->allFiles();
            foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $file) {
                // store the file and set it's path to the value of the key holding it
                if ($file->isValid()) {
                    $input[$key] = $file->store('fb_uploads', 'public');
                }
            }
```

Make sure the form tags contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for the data to be sent.

I hope this helps.